# Exist project(software, solution) for backing documents in many different clouds?

Tags: repository, backup

I would like to know if exist project(software, solution) for backing file in many different clouds.

I mean if exist a project similar to https://www.duplicati.com/, I would like to centralize all of backups to different clouds as AWS, Google, etc. In at same application or software, in the other words it could be a center of backup configuration.

Thank you.

information about a software solution similiarhttps://www.duplicati.com/.